# Grails 3 Example for oauth consumer

Tags: spring-security, oauth, grails-3.0

already googled a lot, but all results seem to link to oauth provider plugins, examples and tutorials.

I am looking for a oauth consumer example for Grails 3 which let's me login a user to my app with a google account.

One example I've found uses pac4j : https://github.com/pledbrook/talk-submissions/blob/master/build.gradle

I would like to see an example which is based only on spring-security.

Is such an example already available? If not, which plugins should do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the spring-security-rest plugin.  AFAIK, this is about as much help as the Grails plugin ecosystem is going to provide for this (as of today).

http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest

Specifically for the google login use-case:

http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/#_google